# How to fix, Karbonn titanium S6 Looping at Logo

Tags: android

Today I rooted my Karbonn Titanium S6 using Baidu Root and removed some of pre-installed apps (Not the system apps). But now it is looping at logo after the reboot. 
I tried install fresh ROM but unfortunately USB debugging is not enabled.
Is there any way to fix this issue? And How to enable USB debugging in this case. 
In addition,  even after Installing the Phone Driver and Universal ADB Driver it is not detected by the Smart Phone Flash tool.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the right place to ask this.

Comment: Please help me by moving to a right place

Comment: [Here](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot the phone in Fastboot mode and 
Connect it to your pc using USB cable (#original_recommended).
Flash the recovery.img ,boot.img or Official Stock ROM
You will need fastboot tool (Get it here : http://p.pw/baim02 ) and 
Here is a video tutorial
http://p.pw/baim0E

Gud Luck!!

Comment: Is it possible to Enable USB debugging with FastBoot?